# How can be optimized merging of two arrays of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I would like to optimize my code for `CPU` and `memory` consumption. In my function I need to merge two arrays of object into one array. Like `UNION`, all the `id`s of the objects in the array have to be unique. I do not want to use third party libraries like `Underscore`.

**This is my function:**

```
var presentation_slides = [
  {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "results"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "slide"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "type": "questions"
  }]

for(var i = 0; i < new_length; i++) {
    var my_slide = presentation_slides.filter(function (obj) { return obj.id == i })[0]
    if(!my_slide) {
        presentation_slides.push({"id": i, "type": "slide"});
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
var presentation_slides = [
  {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "results"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "slide"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "type": "questions"
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "type": "slide"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "type": "slide"
  }]
```

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Some tests for comparison: http://jsperf.com/how-can-be-optimized-merging-of-two-arrays-of-objects

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but what is the source of the array? Can this be solved server side?

Comment: in your code i see only one array in which you add new objects, maybe rewrite you question with a more accurate code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `some` instead of `filter`, i have added a `code snipet` to your `jsperf`, which is faster...

check this: [.....jsperf.....](http://jsperf.com/how-can-be-optimized-merging-of-two-arrays-of-objects/3)

```
for (var i = 0; i < new_length; i++) {

    if (!presentation_slides.some(function(obj) { return obj.id == i}))
        presentation_slides.push({ "id": i, "type": "slide" });
}
```

Comment: Very nice! I need to check `.filter()` and `.some()`!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to merge two arrays, then you can use `Array.concat()`:

```
var array1 = [
    { id: 1, type: "orange" },
    {id: 3, type: "apple" },
    { id: 4, type: "banana" } ],
    array2 = [
        { id: 8, type: "strawberry" },
        { id: 9, type: "raspberry" }
    ];

var array3 = array1.concat(array2);
```

`array3` will contain all the elements from `array1` and `array2`.

This will not check to see if the IDs are unique though.

Comment: Thank you, but it must be unique. That is why I mentioned union.

Comment: @KamilMaraz I see - I didn't understand `UNION` - I mustn't be familiar with it's origin programming language.

Answer (score 0):

also, reverse loops are a little faster:

```
var i = new_length;
while (i--) {
    if (!presentation_slides.some(function(obj) { return obj.id == i })) {
        presentation_slides.push({ "id": i, "type": "slide" });
    }
}
```

check this [...jspref...](http://jsperf.com/how-can-be-optimized-merging-of-two-arrays-of-objects/3)

Comment: This concept I have tried many times, but in chrome that is rarely the case. From my experience, even in the jsperf test you created, is reverse loop slower.

Comment: yes !!!!!, when i was added and run the reverse loop to jsperf, it were a little faster, but now, its a little slower... but i think `reverse loops` are a little faster yet :D

Comment: i was run it again, and this time `reverse loop` were faster, and i took a screen shot... check this: http://tinypic.com/r/e05z60/8

Comment: I think V8 optimizes it anyway... Check this: http://thibaultlaurens.github.io/javascript/2013/04/29/how-the-v8-engine-works/